# Change paragraph color and text color on invalid (incorrect answer)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am designing a quiz type page, requirement is this:

There will be a question with **4 different answers**, when a user selects wrong answer the paragraph color and the background color should be change. **and link should be disabled when some one click again previous clicked link should not be opened** Here is a sample code. I am trying to do this in the following way:

```
Que - 1. Here is a questions ?

<p><a class="correct"   href="#">Answer-1</a></p>
<p><a class="incorrect" href="#">Answer-2</a></p>
<p><a class="incorrect" href="#">Answer-3</a></p>
<p><a class="incorrect" href="#">Answer-4</a></p>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: thanks edit this please !!!

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: thanks I will do the same .. but I researched and doing this last one week .... still I will do more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
function handleClick(answerObject) {
    if(answerObject.className.indexOf("incorrect") > -1) {
        document.getElementById("paragraph").style.backgroundColor = "red";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("paragraph").style.backgroundColor = "green";
    }

    setTimeout(function() { document.getElementById("paragraph").style.backgroundColor = '#FFFFFF'; }, 500);
}
</script>

<p id="paragraph" style="padding:2%">
This is a question.... BLA BLA BLA
</p>

<p><a class="correct"   href="#" onclick="handleClick(this);">Answer-1</a></p>
<p><a class="incorrect" href="#" onclick="handleClick(this);">Answer-2</a></p>
<p><a class="incorrect" href="#" onclick="handleClick(this);">Answer-3</a></p>
<p><a class="incorrect" href="#" onclick="handleClick(this);">Answer-4</a></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: just like this website quiz please check .. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_online_quiz.htm

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `:focus` or `:active` pseudo

```css
.incorrect:focus {background: red; color: #fff;}
```

```html
<p><a class="correct"   href="#">Answer-1</a></p>
<p><a class="incorrect" href="#">Answer-2</a></p>
<p><a class="incorrect" href="#">Answer-3</a></p>
<p><a class="incorrect" href="#">Answer-4</a></p>
```

Comment: great @aaron ..but link should be disable after clicking on wrong or right answer

Comment: that isn't what you asked in your question?